# Trouble cross compiling cURL with ssl for ARM9

Tags: linux, gcc, curl, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile curl with enabled ssl option for ARM9 but somehow I can't get it enabled.

I cross compiled openssl before and then I tried to run ./configure with ssl option:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/asphantix/Tools/owa33a/openssl/openssl-1.0.1c/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/asphantix/Tools/owa33a/openssl/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl" ./configure --with-ssl --without-ca-bundle --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

it runs through but this is what I get everytime:

```
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

curl version:     7.28.1
Host setup:       arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Install prefix:   /usr/local
Compiler:         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,cyassl,axtls,winssl} )
SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
krb4 support:     no      (--with-krb4*)
GSSAPI support:   no      (--with-gssapi)
SPNEGO support:   no      (--with-spnego)
TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
ipv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
Built-in manual:  enabled
--libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
ca cert bundle:   no
ca cert path:     no
LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
RTSP support:     enabled
RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP
```

I also tried to set the following:

```
export AR=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
export AS=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as
export LD=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
export RANLIB=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export NM=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm
```

Here's the config.log:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3985208/config.log

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the `crypto` library.

```
configure:20710: checking for CRYPTO_lock in -lcrypto
configure:20732: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o conftest -O2 -Wno-system-   headers -isystem /home/asphantix/Tools/owa33a/openssl/openssl-1.0.1c/include  -   L/home/asphantix/Tools/owa33a/openssl/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl  conftest.c -lcrypto  -lrt >&5
/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
...
configure:20741: result: no
```

Comment: yes, the library includes were wrong. I got it compiled. However it's wrong. I get a bus error on the target host.
The target is arm926ej-s. I'm giving up on cross compiling curl...

Comment: @mherwig post another question, don't give up. However be specific, descriptive.